# Pyplot savefig memory leak - alternative?

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory-leaks

Is there an alternative to pyplot to plot some graphs in python?
I'm having some memory leaks which make my project impossible to complete.

I've tried the usual recommended "solutions" of using plt.close(), plt.clf(), etc with and without a single fig = plt.figure() object, but it did absolutely nothing.

I also tried using a thread but it's the first time I used it in python so I may have done it wrong :

```
import gc
import psutil
from threading import Thread
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def plot_func():
    plt.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
    plt.savefig('plot_test.png')
    plt.close()

gc.collect()
init_mem_tot = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
for i in range(20):
    init_mem = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
    thread = Thread(target=plot_func)
    thread.start()
    thread.join()

    # tried with and without those the two following lines
    del thread
    gc.collect()
    new_mem = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
    print("Memory : %f, previous : %f. (%f difference)" % (new_mem, init_mem, init_mem - new_mem))

final_mem = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
print("Final : %f, Init : %f. (%f tot difference)" % (final_mem, init_mem_tot, final_mem - init_mem_tot))
```

Result gives :

```
Memory : 107.441406, previous : 102.687500. (4.753906 difference)
Memory : 108.578125, previous : 107.445312. (1.132812 difference)
Memory : 109.941406, previous : 108.578125. (1.363281 difference)
Memory : 111.281250, previous : 109.941406. (1.339844 difference)
Memory : 112.195312, previous : 111.281250. (0.914062 difference)
Memory : 113.281250, previous : 112.195312. (1.085938 difference)
Memory : 114.535156, previous : 113.281250. (1.253906 difference)
Memory : 115.640625, previous : 114.535156. (1.105469 difference)
Memory : 116.707031, previous : 115.640625. (1.066406 difference)
Memory : 117.843750, previous : 116.707031. (1.136719 difference)
Memory : 119.175781, previous : 117.843750. (1.332031 difference)
Memory : 120.367188, previous : 119.175781. (1.191406 difference)
Memory : 121.507812, previous : 120.367188. (1.140625 difference)
Memory : 122.660156, previous : 121.507812. (1.152344 difference)
Memory : 123.937500, previous : 122.660156. (1.277344 difference)
Memory : 124.828125, previous : 123.937500. (0.890625 difference)
Memory : 126.406250, previous : 124.832031. (1.574219 difference)
Memory : 127.671875, previous : 126.406250. (1.265625 difference)
Memory : 128.585938, previous : 127.671875. (0.914062 difference)
Memory : 129.699219, previous : 128.589844. (1.109375 difference)
Final : 129.699219, Init : 102.687500. (27.011719 tot difference)
```

If those are all the solutions, is there an other way for me to plot stuff?

Comment: So I'm not sure what happens if you run matplotlib outside the main thread. But it might be ok, if there is no GUI involved. In such case you can use the `"Agg"` backend to save memory. I then do not see a difference between using threading or not, and memory cosumption increases only very slightly. If that slight increase is evitable, I don't know. Probably a better memory profiling would be needed to see what's going on.

Comment: It's actually savefig which causes problems. And 1mo/plot is way too big for my application since I run out of memory very quickly (even a bit increase would be frustrating as there is no reason for it to increase at all). I need it to not increase whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

If not using threading and not using pyplot, only a very slight memory consumption increase is observed. I do not know where it comes from, but it might be bearable.

```
import gc
import psutil
from matplotlib.figure import Figure


def plot_func():
    fig = Figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot()
    ax.plot([1,2,3], [1,2,3])
    fig.savefig('plot_test.png')

init_mem_tot = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
for i in range(100):
    init_mem = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20

    plot_func()
    gc.collect()
    new_mem = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
    print("Memory : %f, previous : %f. (%f difference)" % (new_mem, init_mem, init_mem - new_mem))

final_mem = psutil.Process().memory_info().rss / 2**20
print("Final : %f, Init : %f. (%f tot difference)" % (final_mem, init_mem_tot, final_mem - init_mem_tot))
```

Output: (Note how 95% are by the very first plot)

```
Memory : 48.113281, previous : 44.140625. (-3.972656 difference)
Memory : 48.152344, previous : 48.113281. (-0.039062 difference)
Memory : 48.195312, previous : 48.152344. (-0.042969 difference)
Memory : 48.199219, previous : 48.195312. (-0.003906 difference)
Memory : 48.199219, previous : 48.199219. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.199219, previous : 48.199219. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.257812, previous : 48.199219. (-0.058594 difference)
Memory : 48.257812, previous : 48.257812. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.265625, previous : 48.257812. (-0.007812 difference)
Memory : 48.265625, previous : 48.265625. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.269531, previous : 48.265625. (-0.003906 difference)
Memory : 48.273438, previous : 48.269531. (-0.003906 difference)
Memory : 48.273438, previous : 48.273438. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.273438, previous : 48.273438. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.273438, previous : 48.273438. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.273438, previous : 48.273438. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.281250, previous : 48.273438. (-0.007812 difference)
Memory : 48.285156, previous : 48.281250. (-0.003906 difference)
Memory : 48.285156, previous : 48.285156. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.285156. (-0.027344 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.312500, previous : 48.312500. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.312500. (-0.003906 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.316406, previous : 48.316406. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.316406. (-0.003906 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Memory : 48.320312, previous : 48.320312. (0.000000 difference)
Final : 48.320312, Init : 44.140625. (4.179688 tot difference)
```

Comment: Do you think that this no `pyplot` approach is generally viable?

Comment: @gboffi I have no idea. One will need to use a better memory profiling tool to find out what the leftovers are.

Comment: I am sorry I was not clear in my Q: I am not so much interested in memory usage rather I'd like to understand if, from your informed POV, using the `pyplot` namespace adds real convenience for the user/programmer.  I have found (advanced) tutorials where the only use for `plt` was `plt.subplots()` and `plt.show()`...

Comment: @gboffi Ok, seems like a completely different question. Of course pyplot is useful, as it allows to create a figure which will later be shown in an interactive GUI precisely in one line (`plt.figure()`). But it adds a lot of overhead in case you only want to save a picture of the figure.

Comment: 1st of all, thank you. Let's see if I have understood: `fig = matplotlib.figure.Figure()` is essentially non-interactive and the overhead introduced by `pyplot.figure()` is (mostly) associated with the complicate machinery required to provide user-interaction.

Comment: If you produce a `Figure()` you can always add it do a `FigureCanvas` then use the Gui tool to create some window and place the canvas into that window. (Example [here](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/user_interfaces/embedding_in_qt_sgskip.html)). Those are a lot of lines compared to the two you need for pyplot. pyplot will automatically (or based on user choice) select a GUI ("backend") and do all of the above for you. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1,4]); plt.show()` is then all you need.