# How to get more fps when plotting and saving images using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, memory, memory-leaks, spectrogram

The below code walks over a directory of audio files (~50k) and converts them to spectrogram images and saves each of them in the same top level directory.

```
def plot_and_save(denoised_data, f_name):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    i = 0
    # Add this line to show plots else ignore warnings
    # plt.ion()

    ax.imshow(denoised_data)

    ax.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
    ax.get_yaxis().set_visible(False)
    fig.set_size_inches(10, 10)
    fig.savefig(
        f"{f_name}" + "_{:04d}.png".format(i),
        dpi=80,
        bbox_inches="tight",
        quality=95,
        pad_inches=0.0)

    ax.draw_artist(ax.xaxis)
    ax.draw_artist(ax.yaxis)

    i += 1


def standardize_and_plot(sampling_rate, file_path_image):
    logger.info(f"All files will be resampled to {sampling_rate}Hz")

    output_image_folder = "PreProcessed_image/"

    for dirs, subdirs, files in os.walk(file_path_image):
        for i, file in enumerate(files):
            if file.endswith(('.wav', '.WAV')):
                logger.info(f"Pre-Processing file: {file}")
                data, sr = librosa.core.load(
                    os.path.join(dirs, file), sr=sampling_rate, res_type='kaiser_fast')
                target_path = os.path.join(output_image_folder, dirs)

                pcen_S = apply_per_channel_energy_norm(data, sr)

                denoised_data = wavelet_denoising(pcen_S)

                work_dir = os.getcwd()

                if not os.path.exists(target_path):
                    os.makedirs(target_path)

                os.chdir(target_path)

                f_name, _ = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(file))

                plot_and_save(denoised_data, f_name)

                os.chdir(work_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    chunkSize = 3
    sampling_rate = 44100
    file_path_audio = 'Recordings'
    file_path_audio = "data/"
    output_audio_folder = "PreProcessed_audio/"

    file_path_image = os.path.join(output_audio_folder, file_path_audio)

    standardize_and_plot(sampling_rate, file_path_image)
```

How can I optimize the plot_and_save() method? It takes a lot of time (around 2-3 fps) for saving those many images in the disk. I am using Google Colab for this purpose.

After around half-an hour of saving these images, colab crashes stating all the RAM was used. Is there a way to know where the memory-leak is? Or is there a way to fasten the plotting and saving process?

Comment: What's the purpose of `ax.draw_artist(ax.xaxis)`? In any case try to close the figures after having saved them, `plt.close(fig)`.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest  To me, this seems similar to [pyplot-savefig-memory-leak-alternative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408210/2749397) of a few days ago, it's again memory exhausted after repeated plotting and save figures.

Comment: @gboffi Yes, but the leak there is rather small. Here it's first off important to close the figure.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest I'm trying to speed up matplotlib as given here: https://bastibe.de/2013-05-30-speeding-up-matplotlib.html.It's better to keep the plot and just update the data rather than close it everytime and redraw everything I guess

Comment: Oh, so what's shown in the link is how you speed up matplotlib on screen. The aim there is to not draw the complete figure in each refresh. This however is meaningless for *saving* figures, because when saving, the figure needs to be drawn in completeness.

Comment: So is there a way to fasten what I'm trying here? My other approach was to use `fig.canvas.draw()` and `fig.canvas.flush_events()` rather than `ax.draw_artist`. Not much faster, but somewhat better

Comment: So your primary problem is to prevent crashes, right? I would start by closing the figures. If that prevents memory overflow, one can think of optimizing further. One option is, as shown in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56408210/2749397) by not using pyplot. Also, not creating a new figure each call would be beneficial, i.e. create one figure with an image, update that image via `image.set_data()`. Further, not using the `"tight"` option would gain a bit.

Comment: without`"tight"` it draws white borders which I certainly don't require. Could you write an answer so I could check it out?

Comment: Use the code in the link.